# Group values within a key through a list

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to group values from a key into a list of values by splitting them up after each quotation mark that appears. So each landmark is assigned a list of locations,
for example:

```
{'Landmarks': ['Great norwich', 'Larger building', 'Leaning building'],
 'location':  ['North 28th Street',
               'Stadium High School',
               '',
               'Charles Bridge',
               "St Vitus' Cathedral",
               '',
               'All Saints Church',
               'Royal Courts of Justice',
               'Lonsdale Road']
}
```

Expected output:

as dictionary:

```
{'Landmarks': ['Great norwich', 'Larger building', 'Leaning building'],
 'location':  [['North 28th Street', 'Stadium High School'],
               ['Charles Bridge', "St Vitus' Cathedral"],
               ['All Saints Church', 'Royal Courts of Justice', 'Lonsdale Road']]
}
```

or as DataFrame:

```
Landmarks               Locations
Great norwich           ['North 28th Street','Stadium High School']
Larger building         ['Charles Bridge','St Vitus' Cathedral',]
Leaning building        ['All Saints Church','Royal Courts of Justice','Lonsdale Road']
```

I have tried:

```
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I get the error ->

> arrays must all be same length

I can remove the quotation marks with:

```
for v in data.values():
    if ('') in v:
        v.remove((''))
```

Though how do I assign all values before the quotation mark as a list before removing, to get the expected value above?

Comment: r u using pandas for this?

Comment: @GhostOps The output could be a pandas output, though I'd be interested to know how its done in the dictionary so I could call ```pd.DataFrame()```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: did u got any error for this?

Comment: Expected input: Some effort.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Early morning for me so it's taking me some time to get into practice. Though I have added some input

Comment: @Stackcans please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69388177/16343464) ;)

Comment: dataframe has that builtin and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach to split the list on `''`. It is using a short list comprehension with`itertools.groupby` and an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (python **≥ 3.8**)

```
from itertools import groupby
d2 = d.copy()
d2['location'] = [G for _,g in groupby(d['location'], ''.__eq__)
                  if (G:=list(g)) != ['']]
```

version for python **< 3.8**:

```
from itertools import groupby
d2 = d.copy()
d2['location'] = [G for _,g in groupby(d['location'], ''.__eq__)
                  for G in [list(g)] if G != ['']]
```

output:

```
{'Landmarks': ['Great norwich', 'Larger building', 'Leaning building'],
 'location': [['North 28th Street', 'Stadium High School'],
  ['Charles Bridge', "St Vitus' Cathedral"],
  ['All Saints Church', 'Royal Courts of Justice', 'Lonsdale Road']]}
```

as DataFrame:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(d2)
          Landmarks                                                     location
0     Great norwich                     [North 28th Street, Stadium High School]
1   Larger building                        [Charles Bridge, St Vitus' Cathedral]
2  Leaning building  [All Saints Church, Royal Courts of Justice, Lonsdale Road]
```

used input:

```
d = {'Landmarks': ['Great norwich', 'Larger building', 'Leaning building'],
     'location': ['North 28th Street',
                  'Stadium High School',
                  '',
                  'Charles Bridge',
                  "St Vitus' Cathedral",
                  '',
                  'All Saints Church',
                  'Royal Courts of Justice',
                  'Lonsdale Road']}
```